# subtraction in ruby no less than 1

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to figure out the best way to have a subtraction block in ruby where the result defaults to `1` if the result is less than `1`.

I tried a ternary operator, but a `0` result is true apparently:

```
(2 - 2) ? (2 - 2) : 1
```

Is there a concise way to express `4 - 2 = 2`, `2 - 2 = 1` and `3 - 2 = 1`?

Comment: In Ruby *only* `nil` and `false` are logically false. Everything else, empty strings, zero, an empty array, they're all considered logically true.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable#`max`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max):

```
def special_subtraction(a, b)
  [a - b, 1].max
end

special_subtraction(4, 2)
#=> 2
special_subtraction(2, 2)
#=> 1
special_subtraction(3, 2)
#=> 1
```

P.S.

> I tried a ternary operator, but a `0` result is true apparently:

In Ruby, everything except for `nil` and `false` is considered truthy.

Comment: `[a - b, 1].max` :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev why you so cool? Perfect one. Can I use it or will you add it as an answer? :P

Comment: Sure, take it :)

Comment: Now that this answer is the only survivor, you ought to add some explanation. "Conditionals greatly complicate your code, the less of them you have, the better, blah blah" :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it is so utterly self-explanatory now that I doubt the answer needs to be any longer than exact contents of your first comment :P

Comment: Though this is clever I like your original answer more because there the intent of the code is very clear.

Comment: Thanks for the code! I like this one better just because I'm writing it into an erb template and the shorter the better.